# How to display Fetch json API response in browser window

Tags: javascript, json, return, fetch

I have tried several examples shown here and elsewhere but I just cannot get to display the JSON response from my API.
It is an image analyzes API and the html/JavaScript code is included below.
My current code is as below and the alert is never shown:

myAPI returns the following JSON:

```
{
   credits: "945.00",
   property: "XYZaaa",
   final: "*****66768",
   cidade: "São Paulo",
   uf: "SP",
   marca: "VW",
   modelo: "TL",
   ano: "1974",
   cor: "Vermelha",
   situacao: "VEÍCULO"
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
 <head>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/var/www/html/images/car.png">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>myAPI</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myForm">
<table align='center' style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr><td align="center"><font size = "5"><b>Leitura de Imagem</b></font><br>
Escolher imagem</td></tr>
<tr><td>

      <input id="inpFile" type="file" accept="image/*" > 
      <button type="submit">Upload</button>
      <br>
      <img src="#" id="localImage" width="400">
    
</td></tr></tbody></table>    
</form>
    <script>
    const imgInput = document.querySelector('input')
    const imgEl = document.querySelector('img')
    imgInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
    if (imgInput.files && imgInput.files[0]) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (e) => {
      imgEl.src = e.target.result;
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(imgInput.files[0]);
    }
  })

  const myForm  = document.getElementById("myForm");
  const inpFile = document.getElementById("inpFile");

  myForm.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const endpoint = "myAPI URL";
    const formData = new FormData();
    console.log(inpFile.files);
    formData.append("inpFile", inpFile.files[0]);
    formData.append("countrycode","br");
    formData.append("token","myToken");
    formData.append("vehicledata","true");
    formData.append("imageurl","");

    fetch(endpoint, {
      method: "post",
      body: formData
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => showdata(data));
  });

  function showdata(data){
    alert(data);
  }
  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What Am I missing?
Assistance welcome
Thanks

Just added  .catch(err => { alert(err); });
and it returns: Failed to fetch.

This API is working ok for some time and it responds ok to the following Javascript request:

```
 // Set POST method and ajax file path
xhttp.open("POST", "upload.php?vehicledata="+vehicledata+
                   "&token="+token+
                   "&countrycode=br",
          true);

// call on request changes state
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

    var response = this.responseText;
    if(response == ''){
       alert("Erro no Upload.");
    }else{
       //alert(response);
       const jsonData = JSON.parse(response);
```

The code above is hosted by Apache.
The one with Fetch above is hosted by Node-Red.
The API runs on Node-Red

Assistance welcome
Thanks

---

Hi, after some research the JavaScript code was updated as below:

```
<script>
    const imgInput = document.querySelector('input')
    const imgEl = document.querySelector('img')
    imgInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
    if (imgInput.files && imgInput.files[0]) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (e) => {
      imgEl.src = e.target.result;
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(imgInput.files[0]);
    }
  })

  const myForm  = document.getElementById("myForm");
  const inpFile = document.getElementById("inpFile");

  myForm.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const endpoint = "URL for API";
    const formData = new FormData();
    console.log(inpFile.files);
    formData.append("inpFile", inpFile.files[0]);
    formData.append("countrycode","br");
    formData.append("token","myToken");
    formData.append("vehicledata","true");
    formData.append("imageurl","");

    fetch(endpoint, {method: "post", body: formData })
    .then(function(response) {return response.text(); })
    .then(function(result) {
      let output = "<table><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Provider</th><th>URL</th></thead><tbody>";
      for (let i in result) {
        output += "<tr><td>" + result[i].credits + "</td><td>" + result[i].property + "</td><td>" + result[i].cidade + "</td></tr>";
      }
      output += "</tbody></table>";
      document.getElementById("result").value = output;
      alert("Result: " + output);
    })
    .catch(err => { alert(err); });

  });
</script>
```

I was able to confirm that the API receives the POST variable, receives the image and responds with the desired JSON, for some reason it is not accepted by the FETCH

Alert still returns:
TypeError: Failed to fetch

Again, this API responds correctly to another version of this call that uses Ajax
Thanks

*****------------------------------------*********

Updated code 13/08
Kept trying different suggestions found all over the internet.
Latest one below.
Failed to fetch message no longer a problem but still no data.
In Chrome I get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'encrypt') at the console but not on Microsoft Edge.
But it behaves the same on both.

```
myForm.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const endpoint = "URL for myAPI";
  const form_data = new FormData();
  console.log(inpFile.files);
  form_data.append("inpFile", inpFile.files[0]);
  form_data.append("countrycode","br");
  form_data.append("token","myToken");
  form_data.append("vehicledata","true");
  form_data.append("imageurl","");

  fetch(endpoint, {method: "post", body: form_data })
.then(res => res.text())
.then((out) => {
  let data = JSON.parse(out);
  alert(data);       <<--------- alert returns "[object Object]"
  var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        alert(data[i].credits); <---------------NO ALLERTS HERE
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = 'Name: ' + data[i].credits + ' ' + data[i].modelo;
        mainContainer.appendChild(div);
  }               
})
.catch(function (err) {
     alert('error: ' + err);
});    
});
```

Comment: Try logging the ```formData``` and see if it's sending the exact type and format that the server expects. Probably function ```showData``` is not giving output because it is never called, the reason could be there might be error response from the server. Inspect the developer tools and see the status code and you'll understand.

Comment: Just included .catch(err => { alert(err); }); and it is returning: Failed to fetch. Trying to find the reason. Just edited the question, please check

Comment: Please check revised code and results. Thanks

Comment: What are you getting as output now? Is there any error in the console?

Comment: Dear Badri, thanks for your interest. Please check latest code above. No more Failed to Fetch but still no data. Please check alert probes I included in the code. It may provide clues for those who know JS more them I do. Thanks

Comment: Hi, my current understanding is that it is a Node-Red related problem. If you want to take a look at a simulation I designed and that has the same problem please browse to: https://discourse.nodered.org/t/javascript-on-template-no-fails-to-fetch-json/66392